# Pen-test hard-coded php compare

Tags: php, security

I post today because I have a small problem. In fact I have to do a pen-test for my IT school, and I must bypass a login form coded like this :

```
<?php
if (count($_POST) && (
    $_POST['pseudo'] != 'admin' ||
     $_POST['pass'] != '* HIDDEN *'))
  header('location: index.php');
[...blablabla...] PASSPHRASE [...bliblibli...]
?>
```

I have to get the passphrase, but I cannot do an SQL injection, because the login and the password are stored in the .php file.
Does someone have an idea how to bypass that?

I tried to do like an SQL Injection, but in PHP, like typing : 1!=1))// into the password form, but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I don't understand? You want to hack the login system?

Comment: Is the login running on SSL?

Comment: @Jazerix he already said it's not SQL...

Comment: @Jazerix I don't think so!

Comment: @BenM Yeah, I want to access to the admin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code. It will perform the check only if `$_POST` is not empty. So the solution is: Send no post. You can just login without credentials.

However, I guess your school wants *you* to solve the problem, not the internet community.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I thought about the Bruteforce method, but I thought we could bypass the php code with commentaries.
And at my school, we can use every way to get to our goal :)

Comment: I guess you mis-interpreted this. They want you to think about code. Check my update, it's easy to work around that security "restriction" ;)